# Check the state of gps in android development

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app in which i need to take the users location through fused location provider. Before taking the location i want to check whether the gps is on or not. And i want to do this without using location manager. Any suggestions?

Comment: so you want to check if GPS is on or not, do you also want to enable it if it is off?

Comment: Yes.. without opening the settings. I want to do this in the app itself

Comment: well, a small dialog will pop up asking the user for whether they want to turn GPS on or not, settings will not be opened and GPS will be turned on upon clicking Yes by the user, If this is you want I can post my code

Comment: Yes please. This is exactly what i want.

Comment: I posted my code, you can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw bellow method you can check Location Mode,

```
/**
     * Method is used to check which locatrion mode is selected,
     *
     * @param context
     * @return If return 0 = LOCATION_MODE_OFF, 1 =  LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY & DEVICE_ONLY, 2 = LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING , 3 = LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY
     */
    public static int getLocationMode(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            try {
                return Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                String locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(
                        context.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED
                );
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders)) {
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED is deprecated

Comment: Yes, we know but the reason is the use this need only lower then KitKat so no need to worry about that, And If your app support above KitKat then please remove it,

Comment: Thanks for the informing.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void checkGpsEnabled() {

        LocationSettingsRequest settingsRequest = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
                .setNeedBle(true)
                .setAlwaysShow(true)
                .build();
        SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> response = client.checkLocationSettings(settingsRequest);

        response.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {

            }
        });
        response.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    try {

                        resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(LocationFusedActivity.this, 1002);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```